# Can the actions of another entity remain truly inscrutable?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, worldbuilding-process

> **Inscrutable**
>
> Impossible to understand or interpret.

Here on Worldbuilding SE, I see quite a few questions and more answers that mention the inscrutability of the actions of intelligent non-human entities.  However, if we were to create our worlds with our intelligent non-humans acting randomly simply *in order* to be inscrutable, rather than acting with motives that are not explained to those observing our worlds, I believe that we run the risk of not building the best worlds we can, basically by taking unjustified short-cuts.

However, this depends upon the intelligence and [extelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extelligence) of the observers.  As the only real observers of a fictional world, an *individual* human may find the actions of a fictional character or group to be inscrutable, and due to differences in the nature of their intelligence, our fictional characters and groups may also find the actions of others to be inscrutable.  A cat or dog probably finds some of the actions of humans to be inscrutable... but we're smarter than they are, and they can't talk to each other about their problems.

However, in the real world, while a person has a finite intelligence, and may very well find the actions of another entity inscrutable, people also have specialities, and we can communicate with each other and cooperate in order to solve problems in a way that other species such as cats and dogs don't appear able to emulate.  A group of people can arrive at an answer to very complex problems that may defeat any single member of that group.

So, my question is, **Can the non-random, non-arbitrary actions of another entity or group, no matter how intelligent that entity or group may be, *remain* inscrutable to us as *as a group*?**

That the actions of others may be - and remain - inscrutable to individuals or members of other species is not in question.  This has nothing to do with language, this is about real and fictional people working out what characters in fictional worlds are doing.

Comment: ... https://philosophy.stackexchange.com , perhaps?

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane, I'm asking about figuring out motives and predicting future actions.  This has nothing to do with language.

Comment: @Qami I'm asking about the practicalities of working out the motives and future actions of another entity, not the philosophical possibility of doing so.  From a worldbuilding context, should we as world builders always keep motives in mind even if not explicitly stating what those motives are?

Comment: Fair enough! Very interesting question, certainly. Reading your question made me think of how Robert Jordan had some very strange stuff (not summarizing b/c spoilers) happen at the end of his series, and specifically instructed Sanderson to never explain what it meant/how it happened. If you know what I'm talking about, can you confirm if this is the sort of thing you're asking about...?

Comment: This seems like something where the answer is up to the discretion of worldbuilder. Do they choose their world to be fundamentally knowable or unknowable.

Comment: We may not know it's motivation but after some investigations and observations, we definitely can tell it's modus operandi and for the purpose of our security this is sufficient for us to either leave it as is or intervenes.

Comment: @sphennings you must be misunderstanding the question, then.  What I'm asking is if enough people gather enough evidence about an entity's actions, can they predict its future actions?  It has *nothing* to do with the worldbuild*er* and everything to do with the observers.  Also, please note the Science-based tag.

Comment: @Qami I haven't read Robert Jordan, so I wouldn't know.  In a way,  I'm asking if an entity that acts according to a set of rules can truly be inscrutable to all observers or groups of observers, whether those observers are real or fictional.  We as worldbuilders need not reveal the secrets of our characters, but that doesn't mean that our audience won't figure out those secrets.

Comment: @MontyWild from reading your comments on the three answers so far, it seems you're looking for a bulletproof argument one way or another, and (I'm guessing) you'd want a logical or philosophical proof of it. I'm wondering if it might help other answerers if you lay down your cards and answer your own question to the best of your ability? If you show us what your intuition and/or current research is telling you, perhaps some of us will have the resources to confirm, amend or refute that position.

Comment: Even today, it is impossible for one person to understand another person's insanity. Yet, in that insanity, the person acts with some type of intelligence but with totally different motivations, drives, and understandings of the world around them.

Comment: @MontyWild You are asking a language and philosophy question without realizing it.  If the other entity can't, or won't, explain itself (or if language and translation only provide a false belief in understanding when that other entity's experiences are different enough from our own) then observers may *guess* at the non-humans' motivations or likely next moves, but they will only be guesses.  Maybe they guess the next move correctly, and maybe they don't.

Comment: Absolutely. Simply having a different experience of time would make them utterly opaque to any number of people either working in concert or individually. . If they could see time as a dimension, their language and strategies would reflect this. Eg: "Ok, I'll meet you at the library, yesterday" They seem serious when they say this. You say "what? You mean tomorrow." "Sure, tomorrow." You arrive and nobody except some kid is there. Why are you there? You woolgathering again? Nah.  As the Nobel Prize winner 87 years in your future will discover, these time dwellers subtly change your brain.

Comment: The problem is that if you associate with them, they spend quite a bit of time nonlinearlly with you. Your brain begins to allow for more plasticity with respect for time, although you'll never leave serial existence. You'll just struggle to lay down new memories. They are unaware, and because of that,  they can't repair. Damn, that's tough. Their faces respond to multiverse events. They speak a pidgin to you, leaving out the parallel subjunctives they use, can you even explain the problem?  They would be inscrutable.

Comment: As to your question, your group of inscrutables will alter their environment, most likely to their benefit. As do we.  There should be some kind of pattern to this activity. Inscrutable means the pattern was too complex for any of our statistical tools to give a replicable prediction of their next action. If they, like us, can separate internal narrative from actions, then all we can do is describe their behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The combined intelligence of all of humanity cannot understand an entity if they are missing the key data required.  You may have individuals that try to glean this information, but they don't have to succeed.

Indeed some inscrutable characters seem to have this in their soul.  The Doctor from Doctor Who is an excellent example.  Sure, he follows rules and patterns, but entire species fail to truly understand *why* he does what he does, including his own race.  That's the glimmer of something that draws us to the Doctor.

There's Hari Seldon, from Foundation by Asimov.  He discovers a way to predict and guide the future.  However to prevent second order effects, he intentionally buries the knowledge of his "psychohistory," failing to sufficiently teach it to his students.  His inscrutability, and the challenges to it, form major plot points in the series.

Another example comes in Manifold Time, by Stephen Baxter.  I wish I had the book on hand to quote it.  He is trying to convince someone of something highly unlikely.  To do so, he pulls out a box of tiny marbles.  He says that there is one black marble, and either ten marbles or a thousand.  The box is big enough that either is possible.  He presses a button to get a random marble out.  A black one comes out.  Inscrutability, he refuses to admit whether there was ten or a thousand, not even to the reader, letting us ponder how deeply he was gambling on that day.

Comment: How can we know that observers won't succeed?  This question is as much about real people who experience our built fictional worlds in our real world as about fictional characters observing other fictional entities in their fictional setting.

Comment: @MontyWild that's an interesting question.  Obviously, it is always possible to be inscrutable by withholding information.  It's at the heart of both deus ex machina and modern cryptography.  I suppose the question becomes not whether it is possible, but whether it is desirable.  That might be more of a Writers.SE question.

Comment: An interesting edge case might be the lyrics from Dream Theater's album Scenes from a Memory.  It's lyrics were inscrutable indeed,and subject to countless theories on the fan forums for the band until their drummer actually posted on one of the many theories that this one was right.  Now, they are no longer inscrutable.  Or perhaps the ending to the movie K-Pax, which I still find inscrutable.

Answer (score 1):

## Shared frame of Reference:

A species must have a shared or at least comprehensible frame of reference with us for us to interpret its motives. We might be able to eventually predict WHAT it will do by its actions, but if the motivation behind it is sufficiently alien, then we may never comprehend it. naturally, language would be the most important of these frames of reference, since communication is central to conveying intent or causality.

We exist in the physical universe, desire to continue existing, want to make more of ourselves, and seek things like information, material goods, and experiences. But what about beings who don't SHARE any of these qualities?

Imagine, for example, a being that emits photons into our universe from a parallel one where the laws of physics are different. We can see it, but the creature is interacting with different matter than we can perceive, and the physical laws it needs to obey don't match our own. just because it tips its third tendril every 17 minutes doesn't mean we may ever deduce why.

An extradimensional being that is able to manifest itself in physical bodies in our universe at will, and supply energy to that body, might behave in such a strange manner that we don't comprehend it. It wants no material things, may have no regard for personal safety, and may be carrying out experiments on things in our universe with such esoteric aims that we simply can't apply our logic to them and expect that we will ever get them.

A being able to see the future will be responding not to a set of motives about what is happening NOW, but instead will be acting out of a desire to shape events that may not occur for centuries. The people observing them will be long dead before the reason for the action (possibly even a tiny action) becomes apparent. Even if there is constant multi-generational observation, a computer or research team may not consider the possibility that the being knew in advance what would happen in a thousand years.

Beings with sufficiently advanced technology could be so resistant to our behaviors that nothing we do is of enough importance as to influence their actions. A nuclear bomb is easily ignored, they pass through normal matter effortlessly, or they resurrect at will and do things for the simple pleasure of experiencing new stimuli.

Comment: The question is [science-based].  This answer... not so much.

Comment: @MontyWild The subject matter is such that it deals with perception and psychology, not chemistry and physics. I tried to ground the examples in some plausibly alien scenarios, but we are talking situations where there is no common basis in our world for understanding. We would understand ants better than these beings.

Comment: The trouble is that these scenarios are not plausible scientifically.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Decide Yourself**

or **How is a Raven Like a Writing Desk?**,

[image]

This riddle is pretty inscrutable. It has several equally valid answers.

> It can produce a few notes, tho they are very flat and it is nevar put with the wrong end first.
>
> The answer lies in the quill: both may be penned, but they can never truly be captive
>
> Because outstanding bills are found on both of them.
>
> Because in French all the letters in bureau are contained in corbeau.

That means no group of experts -- no matter how clever and knowledgeable -- can deduce the correct answer. Put all the smartest people in the universe in a room. With no time limit they must write down the correct answer and drop it down a chute in the middle of the room. They only get one attempt.

This is an impossible task. Even if they write down one of the answers above, the Mad Hatter can just choose a different correct answer from the list, and declare the experts' answer WRONG.

You have a Mysterious Person in your story. You want their motives to remain inscrutable.
The same method works here. Choose several equally reasonable explanations in advance. Then write the story such that they all remain equally valid.

Comment: However, you have given away your Mad Hatter's motive: To always declare that the answer to any riddle asked by the Hatter to be wrong.  Not so inscrutable, really, just obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

Just go into the main Meta site of the Stack Exchange and search for posts from misguided users begging the devs to enforce downvote explanation.

Our own behaviour as a group is inscrutable to ourselves as a group, by design, since the reasoning behind votes is meant to be secret.

If you don't want to go to another site: just here there was a question about what kind of creature looks like a woman. I find the reasoning behind that inscrutable. Even more so that I put an answer there that can be condensed into two words (literally: 'a woman') and, instead of getting flagged as not an answer, got over three hundred positive votes. I find that inscrutable.

The final example is a frame challenge. You say that the actions of lesser creatures are not inscrutable to humanity on account of our wisdom; yet I dare you tell us why did the featherless chicken cross the road?

Answer (score 0):

Inscrutability can also arise if the POV character and the entity being examined don't share systems of ethics/morals. Such systems of behavior will tell someone what the 'right' action is, but if someone else is playing a different game it will be very difficult to make sense of their actions.

Comment: Just because etics and morals may differ from one entity to the next does not mean that an observer who doesn't share them cannot understand them.

Answer (score 0):

The classic British science fiction Series Quatermas dealt with this by having an alien entity that was only partially observed, and which did not operate on human time frames.

The human observers were only able to perceive the very tip of the entities tendrils, rather than the whole entity, and even then they were only aware of the effects that they had on the surrounding area. Rather than the tendrils themselves.

This was compounded by the entity perceiving time differently so that actions which it considered to be concurrent and rapid appeared to be separated by hundreds of years to humans, so that much knowledge was lost in the intervening years.

To the humans it seemed that random events would occur in random locations throughout history, and then either be forgotten or be distorted by myth. Nobody was ever able to observe a large enough piece of the picture over a long enough period of time to be able to determine the motives of the entity. The best that they could do was to use analogies from known science to create hypothesis that they had no way of confirming.

Comment: Sounds like science fantasy to me.

Comment: Quatermas is hard scifi. Most of it was about the activities of a small group of scientists trying to understand the phenomena.